# COM vs tightly wrapped managed c++ objects

Tags: .net, com, unmanaged, managed

So, there is a legacy code that has to be imported into .NET projects.

Which one do you preffer, and why:

- packing it into COM module

or

- making small and tight c++ managed wrapper around it

There is third option of exporting the functions in the DLL, but let's say that we want classes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself, I would rather chew my leg of then go with COM.  There are numerous times when my setup & deployment project collects wrong version of COM .dll (debug instead of release) and smoke-testing EACH build is just bit of an overkill for me.

Once written and tested, managed c++ wrapper never broke.  At least for me.